# Reuse position vertex data with different color for each data

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I want draw a network in openGL with 1Milion data point which they connect to each other with lines. I use VBO and VAO to draw the network and everything is good. But the color of network nodes and lines change to show clustering. I set position and Color index data in one vertex. Now i have two question.
1- I calculate color from a float ColorIndex in Vartex Shader(with a method above the void main()) and pass it to fragment shader for each vertex data. Is it reasonable or should i generate color in code(CPU) and pass the rgb to Vertex Shader in VBO.
2- What is the best way to change color for each vertex data frequently. Should i use two Vertex buffer object for position and color. (I could not use uniform because each data has different color).
Thanks for help...:)

Comment: Since the "color from a float" can vary for each vertex it should be left in the shader instead of changed to CPU. For frequently updated vertices, if you aren't doing it already, you can use `glBufferData(your_type, buffer_size, NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);` and `glBufferSubData(your_type, 0, buffer_size, vertices_data);`.

Comment: Thanks, I use GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW, so I do not change my code.

Comment: Why you use glBufferSubData, I mean you pass data from different arrays, one for the position and one for the color index.

Comment: I've never tried using multiple VBOs at the same time for one shader myself so I don't know if that's possible/easy. You are updating 1M vertices every frame anyways, I don't think buffering only half the data that are more dynamic will really save you significant performance. I think it's sufficient to tell the GPU it's dynamic draw. There's no strict need for `glBufferSubData` just a function that I use that goes with my dynamic draw code. Use a GPU profiler to see if you really need this 50% memory buffer improvement.

Comment: Actually, from your use case, it doesn't sound like buffering different colors every frame, but instead in response to user input. Is it actually unresponsive upon changes? is that why this question was posted? Use a profiler to make sure it's actually the buffering that takes up significant cpu time and not your update logic.